# How can I add 'column shift' layout mode in isotope v2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

I am using isotope v2 and have layout like google plus. In each post/item comments section has dynamic height. Whenever the size of the item increases and I would like to just shift the post below this one. But with isotope v2, calling layout, reshuffles the whole page and disturbs other columns also. In v1, there was a layout mode [masonryColumnShift](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/custom-layout-modes/masonry-column-shift.html)

How can I extend v2 and add this layout mode. Please help!

Comment: You can't, yet. [See this](https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/582)

Comment: Ok. I hope we see this feature soon. For time being I shifted to V1.